# Suggestions on keeping a soon to be 7 year old engaged during summer vacation

Tags: activities

I have a soon to be 7 year old and a soon to be 2 year old. Now that school year is over I'm wondering how to keep her engaged. With the 2 year old, its hard for my wife to balance time with summer camps and stuff but we are planning to enroll her in some art related camp. But I'm looking for some activities that she can do at home that will be cool and interesting to her. Any time tested tips is welcome :)

EDIT: I'm adding this to clarify what I'm exactly looking for. I'm looking for some summer time activities, games and toys that a 7 year old can play alone and also some activities and games that she can do with her 2 year old sister.

Comment: One word:  Pinterest.

Comment: LEGOs. Sports. Read books from the library.

Comment: "cool and interesting to her"  What are her interests? What have you/she done in the past? Without specifics this question may be a little too broad to attract good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracurricular activities for children](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/21129/extracurricular-activities-for-children)

Comment: @CreationEdge: The "Extracurricular activities for children" question is not exactly what I'm asking. The person who raised the question has a different back story and the answer has a parenting angle. Instead I'm just looking for suggestions to keep both my 7 yr and 2 yr old engaged.

Comment: Yasouser, they're definitely different, but also similar. I was actually hoping the linking would increase traffic to the question and draw out a response from *someone*, since there's unfortunately been no response to this at all!

Comment: It's nearly impossible to suggest activities without knowing the children.  One child's fun is another child's torture.  Picking an activity for the children without through to their individual needs and interests is not only likely to not be fun for them, it can make them feel like you don't care enough to learn their actual interests.  To be frank my suggestion would be speak to the children and ask them what they like and would want to do.  Beyond that I think we would need a more detailed question that narrowed down child's interests, and your goals for them, to give any useful advice.

Comment: @dsollen: A 2 yr old or a 7 yr old doesn't know whats interesting to them. Anything thats fun for them is interesting. The parent also doesn't know whats interesting for them unless you introduce it to them. The purpose of the question is to learn what others have tried with their kids and what worked. Maybe it will work, maybe it wont. Like you say what worked for others may not work with my kids but at least I got to try and introduce it to them and see if they like it or not. I'm trying to learn from other parent's experience in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to answer for this year but for next...

I'm a bit biased here (elementary computer teacher) but my suggestion would be to introduce her to [Code.Org](http://Code.Org), a site that uses a variety of games to teach kids coding concepts.  A lot of the games are based off of popular IPs, so for instance right now there is a game where kids can write code to help guide Elsa (from the Frozen movie) through a world.  There is also a game that lets kids modify Flappy Bird to basically make their own version.  It's all just drag and drop with simple commands.  You might be surprised how much a 7 year old can learn about programming with a small bit of guidance.  I've used this site with my classes as low as kindergarten.